# Server Wide DDL Trigger Permissions Issue

Tags: sql-server, trigger, audit, ddl

I am trying to implement a server wide DDL Trigger that will audit the DDL changes across the databases on the server using script very similar to the article found [here](http://sqlandme.com/2011/07/15/sql-server-auditing-schema-changes-using-ddl-triggers/)

The trigger will log the DDL events into one table within one database, however I am coming up against permissions issues and some users, even myself with sysadmin privileges, receive the following error message.

```
Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LogDDLEvent, Line 19
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

I've read about using the `WITH EXECUTE AS` clause and creating a login specifically for the purpose of executing the trigger though this doesn't appear to have resolved the issue.

Could someone advise on the correct method to implement a trigger of this kind and what permissions are required to users or to a specific login to be used in the WITH EXECUTE AS?

EDIT: Some further info

The server is running SQL Server 2008 R2 and the DDL Trigger is set to DDL_EVENTS as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LogDDLEvent
ON ALL SERVER
FOR DDL_EVENTS
AS

DECLARE     @eventInfo XML
SET         @eventInfo = EVENTDATA()

INSERT INTO Tools.audit.DDLEvent
VALUES
(
      REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)')),'T', ' ') -- EventTime
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)')) -- EventType
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)')) -- LoginName
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/UserName)')) -- UserName
      , CAST(HOST_NAME() AS VARCHAR(128)) -- MachineName
      , (SELECT   CAST(client_net_address AS VARCHAR(128))
            FROM  sys.dm_exec_connections
            WHERE Session_id = CONVERT(INT, @eventInfo.value('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SPID)[1]', 'int'))) -- IPAddress
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)')) -- DatabaseName
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)')) -- SchemaName
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)')) -- ObjectName
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)')) -- ObjectType
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)')) -- DDLCommand
      , @eventInfo -- DDLEventXML
)
```

The above script is how I originally created the trigger and this worked fine for me and some other users, though a user who had db_owner role to a particular database kept receiving the error message above.

After trying to implement the WITH EXECUTE AS I found that the trigger would not work for myself.

Comment: I get the error: Msg 1083, Level 15, State 1, Procedure LogDDLEvent, Line 5
OWNER is not a valid option for EXECUTE AS in the context of server and database level triggers.

Comment: Interesting, ok, where is the table that the DDL trigger writes to? And what is "on occasions" - what is different about the occasions when it works and the occasions when it doesn't?

Comment: I have updated the original question. Please ignore the "on occasions" this was me trying out different things in frustration and I can't recall exactly what it was I changed to have it work for me sometimes. However the issue still remained that other users were receiving the error message when trying a ALTER PROCEDURE command.

Comment: Well, `db_owner` on one database means a hill of beans for your `Tools` database, especially if that user's login has no permissions on the destination database. I'm not convinced that you have had permissions errors when the caller was a `sysadmin`, though. Have you considered granting `INSERT` privileges on that table to `public` (or to the set of logins that are eligible for making auditable DDL changes across the instance)?

Comment: Tried your suggestion and didn't work for me. Using WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa' appears to work fine though not sure if these introduces security concerns.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I've been having several forest for the trees moments this week. Not sure what security risks this could introduce - users can't fire the trigger directly, so it will only be called when users who already have DDL privs do something with DDL, and hopefully don't have rights to change what it does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the trigger to EXECUTE WITH 'sa' appeared to do the trick. Not sure if this introduces any security concerns. I tried creating a separate login with permissions only to the Tools database and DDLEvent table but non sysadmin users got errors.

```
CREATE TRIGGER LogDDLEvent
ON ALL SERVER
WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
FOR DDL_EVENTS
AS

DECLARE     @eventInfo XML
SET         @eventInfo = EVENTDATA()

INSERT INTO Tools.audit.DDLEvent
VALUES
(
      REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)')),'T', ' ') -- EventTime
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)')) -- EventType
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)')) -- LoginName
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/UserName)')) -- UserName
      , CAST(HOST_NAME() AS VARCHAR(128)) -- MachineName
      , (SELECT   CAST(client_net_address AS VARCHAR(128))
            FROM  sys.dm_exec_connections
            WHERE Session_id = CONVERT(INT, @eventInfo.value('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SPID)[1]', 'int'))) -- IPAddress
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)')) -- DatabaseName
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)')) -- SchemaName
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)')) -- ObjectName
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)')) -- ObjectType
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)')) -- DDLCommand
      , @eventInfo -- DDLEventXML
)
```